# Search a Dynamic Number of rows in Column A for a specific string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that contains a varying amount of Rows of data in Column A , within this worksheet I need to search for a specific string then copy the data contained in the Cell adjacent to it and paste into Column C, i.e if data was found in A2 then i need to copy the data from B2 and paste into C1. I can easily find and copy when the string appears once but the string will appear more than once 100% of time. here is when i run into issues.

The temporary code I have written for ease of understanding, searches the spreadsheet for the last Mention of A, get the row number, copy the B cell for that row number then pastes the value into C1.

I guess you need to use range variables for this but not 100% sure how to do it.

i have found no way to copy all mentions of A into a column, or ideally sum up the contents of the B cells. (I can do this, just long winded)

Ive placed my code below.

```
Sub ValueFinder()
Dim LastALocation As String
Dim ValueContent As String

LastALocation = Range("A:A").Find(What:="A", after:=Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ValueContent = Cells(LastALocation, 2)
Cells(1, 3) = ValueContent


End Sub
```

The spreadsheet that its using for more information, contains A,B,C on a loop in Column A and the odd numbers in Column B.

Thanks for any help your able to provide.

Mark

Comment: So, are you wanting to search Col. A for a word (`A`), and copy all instances of that into column B, starting row 2 and going down as more are found?  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Not quite, I am wanting to search Column A for all mentions of (A). For each mention of A take the value of the Cell in Column B that corrosponds to that row location of (A) then paste the value found Column B into C1.             
For example if (A) is found in Row 1,4,7,10 etc then copy the contents of B1, B4, B7, B10 etc into C1,C2,C3,C4. etc Hope this helps, been stuck on this for ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look for a string in Column A, and add to Column C the same row's B Column Value.

```
Sub find_move()
Dim foundCel As Range
Dim findStr As String, firstAddress As String
Dim i As Long
i = 1
findStr = "A"
Set foundCel = Range("A:A").Find(what:=findStr)
If Not foundCel Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = foundCel.Address
    Do
        Range("C" & i).Value = foundCel.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Set foundCel = Range("A:A").FindNext(foundCel)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While Not foundCel Is Nothing And foundCel.Address <> firstAddress
End If
End Sub
```

Note: You should add the worksheet in front of all the range values, i.e. `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(...`

Comment: This is great works like a treat :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub LookingForA()
    Dim s As String, rng As Range, WhichRows() As Long
    Dim rFound As Range

    ReDim WhichRows(1)

    s = "A"
    Set rng = Range("A:A")
    Set rFound = rng.Find(What:=s, After:=rng(1))
    WhichRows(1) = rFound.Row
    Cells(1, 3) = Cells(rFound.Row, 2)

    Do
        Set rFound = rng.FindNext(After:=rFound)
        If rFound.Row = WhichRows(1) Then Exit Do
        ReDim Preserve WhichRows(UBound(WhichRows) + 1)
        WhichRows(UBound(WhichRows)) = rFound.Row
        Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3) = Cells(rFound.Row, 2)
    Loop
End Sub
```

This code builds column **C**.  It also builds an internal array of the row numbers in the event they are needed later.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To read about dynamic arrays:

[Dynamic Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716275%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

or Google:

*Excel VBA dynamic array*

Comment: This works great on the test. I now have a few question, so I can modify it to work with the main macro mainly about syntax and naming conventions . 1st - What does "ReDim" mean? 2- What does "ReDim Preserve" do? - Is that keeping whats in the ReDim variable? 3 - Ubound? No idea what this could means or does? Thanks

Comment: @CptGoodar  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: This works great and is ealisly modded and upgraded to suit the main needs. Thanks again :)